Expecting your comments to structure my project?
I am developing an binary classification project. Initially I got a dataset including real data in 3290 rows and 15 columns. Then using CTGAN network I generated synthetic dataset with 100000 rows. Then I  shuffled these two datasets and obtain 1 dataset. My target variable is highly imblananced (Yes : 23175,  No: 76825).                                  I have following questions regarding my project?
1. There are 7 categorical predictors with 4 binary categorical columns(Gender, MaritalStatus, etc.) others are non binary categorical variables(Province, District, etc). What are the encoding technique should I used?
2. Is it important to handle the data imbalance issue here,  If so what are the techniques should I used to handle this imbalance issue ?
3. Non of my numerical variables are normally distributed. Is it important to handle this issue? If so, what are the  techniques I need to use (such as transformations if needed)?
4. Do i need to standardize or normalize my data? If so why is that?
5. What are the Feature selection techniques I should use here?
6. What is the order of my project. Please order the following .  (Data imbalance issue handling/ Encoding categorical variables / Transforming numerical data/ Standardizing or normalizing numerical data / Feature Selection \ Modeling)
7. finally can I use neural network for this, if so what are the NN types that I can use
I know this is a long question,  thank you for you time and commitment for answering these questions.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can use the search function of this site and study the previous answers, as most of the questions are very common and have been discussed here before.
